# Help with real-analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\mathit{n \in \Bbb{R}}$ consider a polynomial $\mathit{}p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ...+a_n x^n$ with real coefficients. ($\mathit{a_n \neq 0}$ and all coefficients $\in \Bbb{R}$).

If $\mathit{x_0} \in \Bbb{R}$ and $\mathit{p(x_0) \neq 0}$ shows that there is $\mathit{\varepsilon \gt 0}$ such, if $\mathit{|x - x_0| \gt \varepsilon}$ then $\mathit{p(x)}$ has the same sign as $\mathit{p(x_0)}$.

I'm tring to solve this without using continuity, integrability and derivability. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't see how you can prove it without continuity. Hint using continuity: there are only finitely points where $p$ is zero, and the distance between $x_0$ and any of these points is positive. Consider the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Btw, presumably $|x - x_0| > \epsilon$ is a typo and should be $|x - x_0| < \epsilon$.

Comment: i need to prove it without continuity... i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use local boundedness of polynomials? This follows from continuity since a continuous function is bounded on any interval $[a,b]$, but maybe there's some other way of looking at it. Then using the factor theorem for polynomials, we have that
$$p(x) - p(x_0) = q(x)(x-x_0) \implies |p(x) - p(x_0)| = |q(x)|\cdot |x-x_0|$$ 
for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for some polynomial $q$. Therefore if $|q(x)|$ is bounded near $x_0$ in any way (by $C$ let's say), choosing $\epsilon = \frac{p(x_0)}{C}$ yields
$$ |p(x) - p(x_0)| = |q(x)|\cdot |x-x_0| < C\cdot\frac{p(x_0)}{C} = p(x_0)$$
and so $p(x)$ has the same sign as $p(x_0)$ in that interval.

Edit: You can prove boundedness of polynomials without continuity; setting the constants $D= |x_0| + 1$ and $B = \max\{b_0,\ldots,a_n\}$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x| \leq D$ we have that
$$|q(x)| = |b_nx^n + \ldots + b_1x + b_0| \leq |b_nx^n| + \ldots + |b_1x| + |b_0| \leq BD^n + \ldots + BD + B, $$
the right-hand side a constant, and so certainly $q$ is bounded on the interval $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$. To finish just make $\epsilon = \min\left\{1,\frac{p(x_0)}{C}\right\}$.

Comment: I think you want to factor as $p(x) - p(x_0) = q(x) (x-x_0)^k$, where $q(x_0)\ne 0$.

Comment: We could do that, but it is not essential to the proof because we just want $q(x)$ to be small near $x_0$, so it's ok if it is 0.

Comment: im new in this mathematical vision of proving everything... it's hard to think in that way you made. anyway, thanks.

Comment: The key to this proof is that polynomials factor nicely; if $r$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $x-r$ divides $p(x)$ and so we can factor $p(x)$ as $(x-r)q(x)$ for some other polynomial $q$. More generally, $x-x_0$ always divides $p(x)-p(x_0)$ and so $p(x)-p(x_0) = (x-x_0)q(x)$ for some other polynomial $q$. From this we see that the difference between $p(x)$ and $(x_0)$ is simply the product of the difference between $x$ and $x_0$ with $q(x)$. Therefore if we want to show $p(x)$ stays close to $p(x_0)$, we need this difference to be small, which we can do by showing that $q(x)$ is small near $x_0$.

Comment: Now it makes more sense haha.

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $\Delta$ is a real variable, $q(\Delta) = p(x_0+\Delta)-p(x_0)$ is a polynomial in $\Delta.$
Show that the constant term of $q(\Delta)$ is zero. 
Figure out how small you have to make $\epsilon$ so that $\lvert \Delta\rvert<\epsilon$ guarantees that $\lvert q(\Delta) \rvert < \lvert p(x_0)\rvert.$